# VB.NET Embedding Resources From Front End

Tags: vb.net

I have a small program that basically houses PDF files. So far I've been embedding the PDF files in the back end and having to remake the program everytime I want to add another.

I'm wondering if its possible to embed a resource from the front end of the program?

I don't want to use a database or folder structure if I can help it as I'd like the program to be easily portable, without any way of becoming detatched from the database.

TIA

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a way to achieve something like this. To embed the files, you will have to recompile the library anyway. I'd suggest directory structure to go with. Using relative path for directory structure will  not hamper much with portability.

Comment: I thought it would probably by that way, but you never know! Thanks for the info